# Python: Pandas replace with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace the data using Pandas. 
Following is my aim -

1. Remove alphabets from `temperature` and `windspeed` columns. `32 F`
   will be replaced by `32` and `6 mph` will be replaced by `6`.
2. Convert all negative numbers in `temperature` and `windspeed` to
   `NaN`. `-99999` will be converted to `NaN`.
3. Convert all `0` in `event` to `No Event`

Following is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
input_data = {'day': ['1/1/2017', '1/4/2017', '1/5/2017', '1/6/2017', 
                         '1/7/2017', '1/8/2017', '1/9/2017', '1/10/2017', '1/11/2017'],
             'temperature': ['32 F', -99999, 28, -99999, '32 C', '38 F', 35, 34, 40],
             'windspeed': ['6 mph', 9, -99999, 7, -88888, -99999, '10 kmph', 8, 12],
             'event': ['Rain', 'Sunny', 'Snow', 0, 'Rain', 'Sunny', 0, 'Cloudy', 'Sunny']
      }
weather2 = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
new_weather = weather2.replace({"temperature":{-99999: np.NaN,
                                          -88888: np.NaN,
                                          '[A-Za-z]':''},
                            "windspeed":{-99999: np.NaN,
                                          -88888: np.NaN,
                                          '[A-Za-z]':''},
                            "event":{0:'No Event'}},regex=True)
```

The output is as follows -

[image: After code run]

Only regex is changed. How can I combine regex with other replace?

Comment: Can you change picture of intput data to text? [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Added code text for input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the beginning your column type should be string , all the `number` here should be string type

```
new_weather = weather2.replace({"temperature":{'-99999': np.NaN,
                                          '-88888': np.NaN,
                                          '[A-Za-z]':''},
                            "windspeed":{'-99999': np.NaN,
                                          '-88888': np.NaN,
                                          '[A-Za-z]':''},
                            "event":{'0':'No Event'}},regex=True)
```

If you want to know more information , try

```
weather2.applymap(type)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Making all `numbers` as `string` solved the issue.

Comment: @Main yep , yw~ :-) happy coding